# Question regarding web services security

Tags: web-services

I would just like to know how the service.jks Transport level security being handled.

Let's say I have 100 clients. Do I need to create 100 service.jks unique for each the clients?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying if these Wikipedia articles could be helpful:

[Transport_Layer_Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

[Web Services Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security)